# Least-squares regularization matrix is not positive definite?

Tags: matrices, least-squares, regularization

I am fitting data $(x_i,y_i)$ to the following model:
$$
f(x) = \sum_j a_j g_j(x) = a^T g(x)
$$
where $g_j(x)$ are well-conditioned basis functions (in my application they are B-splines, but I don't think that matters for this question).

I want to regularize the result by smoothing (damping) the function by minimizing the second derivative. This means my solution $a$ is given by
$$
a = \textrm{argmin } ||y - X a||^2 + \lambda^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left| \frac{d^2 f(x)}{dx^2} \right|^2 dx
$$
where $X_{ij} = g_j(x_i)$ is the least-squares matrix, and the regularization term can be expressed as:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left| \frac{d^2 f(x)}{dx^2} \right|^2 dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( a^T g'' \right)^2 dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a^T g'' g''^T a dx \\
&= a^T \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g'' g''^T dx \right) a \\
&= a^T G a
\end{align*}
where
$$
G_{ij} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d^2 g_i(x)}{dx^2}  \frac{d^2 g_j(x)}{dx^2} dx
$$
So, now my solution is given by the standard form:
$$
a = \textrm{argmin } ||y - X a||^2 + \lambda^2 a^T G a
$$
I was trying to compute the Cholesky factor of $G = L L^T$ so that I could express this as
$$
a = \textrm{argmin } ||y - X a||^2 + \lambda^2 ||L a||^2
$$
so that I can use a generalized SVD or QR approach to solve the system. However, to my surprise, I found that $G$ was not positive definite - it had one zero eigenvalue.

My question is: **shouldn't the matrix $G$ be positive definite as defined above, since the basis function $g_j(x)$ are positive and well-conditioned?** Again, in my application the $g_j(x)$ are B-splines.

I am trying to determine if I made a mistake when computing the $G$ matrix.

**Alternatively, does anyone see another way to compute the regularization matrix $L$, aside from a Cholesky factorization of $G$?**